# Cisco AnyConnect on Fedora

Tags: fedora, vpn, cisco

I have downloaded the setup for Cisco AnyConnect client from our client's secure web URI. This setup script was for 32 bit machine while mine is a 64 bit one. However, I managed to install the client installing 32 bit dependencies of the AnyConnect. However, now when I try to connect to VPN location, it prompts me for `"Warning: The following Certificate received from the Server could not be verified:"` and provide two options `Disconnect or Accept`. I am accepting that certificate but still AnyConnect is continuously prompting me for this certificate accpetance and after some tries it errors out to be "Timed Out". What can be the reason?

Comment: I had a similar problem on Debian, there are some certificates issues often reported for this client, after an hour of mangling with substituting ssl certificates and libraries as some posts suggest, I gave up and installed openconnect package (open version of Cisco AnyConnect VPN client) along with vpnc. Then command `openconnect --script /etc/vpnc/vpnc-script your.vpn.server.com` worked like a charm. I think you may use the similar approach in Fedora.

Comment: Thanks @RuslanKabalin. However, I know about this alternative approach and I have used it via Network Manager which comes default with Fedora. However, problem with this client is that it disconnects me from my LAN and only connects to VPN and sometimes SSH connections are also not made.